# File execution in Unix

Tags: command-line, unix, installation, shell

```
base
   └──────install
   └──────setup
              └───myfile
```

Suppose this is a part of my directory structure in Unix. Is there any difference between these two:

1)

```
base/setup$ myfile
```

2)

```
base/install$ ../setup/myfile
```

I was trying to install something, and the second gave me some library dependency errors. I thought that these two methods are the same. Why is not that so?

Comment: The best way to realise this, I think, is to write full paths:
base/setup/1.sh > base/setup/myfile
base/install/1.sh > base/setup/myfile

Comment: @netme: here "`>`" is not the redirection operator, I meant "`base/setup>`" as a command prompt.

Comment: then, I think, maybe you have wrong paths in myfile.

Comment: It would be better to include error messages or specific unexpected behavior in your question. "Did not work" provides no useful information. You may prefer ">" in your prompt, but when you show it to other people change it to "$" in order to reduce confusion.

Comment: "Did not work"? Which means what exactly?

Comment: @Lawrence Velázquez: got some library dependency errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`base/setup/myfile` and `base/install/../setup/myfile` *are* the same file. The only explanation I can think of is that `base/setup/myfile` is referencing a file with a path relative to your current working directory (e.g: `run ./modules/pre-setup`) - in which case it may make a difference where you are when you run the script.

Answer (score -1):

it may not have worked as myfile could be trying to call or use things in current directory expecting to be located in the base/setup directory but you are in the base/install directory.